# Pi is not working properly red led not glowing and green led blinking

Tags: led

I bought raspberry pi b+ some days ago. It worked properly for some days, but now I face a problem the red LED is not glowing and green LED is blinking along with processor is overheated. Can any one help me to overcome this?

Answer (score 2):

The Foundation has boot problem guides [The Boot Problems Sticky](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151)

For the newer [Pi4 Boot Problems Sticky](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151&sid=ec118b286843110a1175ec84a250a7dc#p1485558)

You likely have a problem with the SD Card, one of the startup files (start.elf, kernel.img or kernel.img) or the SDRAM. Which of these is the problem can be determined by the number of times the green led flashes:

- 3 flashes: start.elf not found
- 4 flashes: start.elf not launched
- 7 flashes: kernel.img not found
- 8 flashes: SDRAM not recognised. You need newer bootcode.bin/start.elf firmware.

More info can be found [here](http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Green_LED_blinks_in_a_specific_pattern)

Comment: A possibly more up-to-date reference for this at the bottom here: https://support.buyapi.ca/article/33-raspberry-pi-act-led-error-patterns